# Issue in parsing Json response in ruby

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

```
  @response = Typhoeus::Request.get(FOUR_SQUARE_API_SERVER_ADDRESS+'search?ll=' + current_user.altitude.to_s + "&query="+ params[:query] + FOUR_SQUARE_API_ACESS_CODE)
   @venues = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@response.body)
   @venues['response']['groups'][0]['items'].each do |venue|
     venue['name']  //working
      venue['name']['location'][0]['address']  //issues
     venue['name']['categories'][0]['id']  //issues
   end
```

Please check inline comments for issues.

[image]

Comment: @rubyprince check the code..venue['name']['location'][0]['address']  //issues
     venue['name']['categories'][0]['id']  //issues are not working

Comment: Maybe you should include the actual JSON (preferably nicely formatted for easy reading) rather than a screenshot.

Comment: @mu really.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/b58XS.png is this not clear enough..If i try to copy json.. alignment issues. Its foursquare venue api response.

Comment: It is difficult to parse the structure of text from a screenshot, it would have been easier if you pasted the JSON into a text editor, reformatted it to look similar to the screen shot, and then pasted that in your question as a code block. In any case, I think I have found the source of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `venue['name']` is a scalar, not an array; secondly, `venue['location']` (which I think you're trying to access) is not encoded as an array, that's just an object:

```
location: {
    address: "...',
    city: "...",
    // ...
}
```

So here you want:

```
venue['location']
```

Then, your `venue['name']['categories'][0]['id']` will fail because, again, `venue['name']` is a scalar; for this one, you want:

```
venue['categories'][0]['id']
```

Comment: +1 from me. If `venue['name']['categories']` worked categories would have to be nested under `name`.